# VS 2017 Publish Database project to Azure fails with error Login failed for user

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database

If I right-click on my database project and select Publish, I select my Target database, enter my credentials, test connection and everything comes back good.

At this point when I click publish it immediately fails and says to check the error list which is empty.

The Output tab shows this error

`An unexpected exception was encountered while modifying the Server Explorer: Login failed for user 'username here'`

I've verified the credentials are correct and can be connected to remotely.

This has worked before. I'm sure the error message is correct but where is it getting the wrong login credentials from?

Comment: Is the user the SQL admin account when you created the database? The account may have permissions to connect, but not access any of the system objects the publish operation uses.

Comment: @virusstorm it is the admin account.

Comment: Any Visual Studio updates installed recently?

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo I'm running the latest not sure when in the timeline updates vs working/not working happened

Comment: Can you connect through SSMS?